# Algorithm - Find a series of Sophie Germain prime numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have a question related to Sophie Germain related algorithm that I'm wondering about.

The Q is as follows: 
A prime number `p` is defined as **'Sophie Germain prime'** if `2p+1` is a prime number as well. For example, 23 is a Sophie Germain prime because 47 is prime. 47 is not Sophie Germain prime because 95 is not prime.

1) Describe an algorithm that gets a prime number `p` and returns `a1, ... , am` that enforces the following:

**a.** a1 = p

**b.** ai+1 = 2ai + 1 (for each 1 <= i <= m-1)

**c.** ai is Sophie Germain prime (for each 1 <= i <= m) but 2am + 1 is not Sophie Germain prime.

For example, if p=2, the output would be `2, 5, 11, 23`.

I thought about the following algorithm.

```
CheckGermain (p)

1. While p is prime (according to AKS algorithm) **and** 2p+1 is prime
   1.1. Print p
   1.2. p <- 2p+1
```

What do you think?

---

2) Describe an algorithm that gets 2 natural numbers a, b (a < b) and checks if there is a Sophie Germain Prime in between [a..b]

Not sure about how to solve this one. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Do *not* use AKS. It is intolerably slow. Use a probable-prime checker like Miller-Rabin or Baillie-Wagstaff, or use a primality prover like Pocklington, but do *not* use AKS.

Comment: Of interest: OEIS [search](https://oeis.org/search?q=Sophie+Germain+prime&language=english&go=Search) for Sophie Germain prime

Comment: @user448810, thanks for that, I'll use the Miller-Rabin one.
Any idea about the second question?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem. For 2, what's wrong with testing each number from a to b to see if it's a Sophie Germain prime?

Comment: How big are the SG primes you are looking for?

Comment: @user448810, can't tell. The question is exactly as given. I don't have any additional details. Why are you asking?

Comment: @PaulHankin, that's the naive solution and it is really not efficient. I believe they are expecting a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: I ask about the size of the SG primes you seek because it affects the answer. If you want small primes, less than 10**9 or so, you can use a sieve to find them; that will be very fast. If you want larger primes, you will need a different approach. You might enjoy [this page](https://programmingpraxis.com/2013/08/06/sophie-germain-primes/) at my blog.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong :

```
     1.2. p <- 2p+1
```

it should go slowly over each integer like p <- p+1

> you don't want to go from p=2 to 2p+1=5 without visiting 3 which is a prime

and add a while condition like and p<=m to limit the **infinite** loop
and inside the loop use if p is prime than if 2p+1 is prime  print p